# Bounties and selecting an answer for a question I asked

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bounties, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148239/i-found-a-jquery-image-rotatation-script-and-adding-hyperlinks-to-the-images-brea) and it received a couple of answers. I'm getting a message that says I may want to ask for a bounty on the question.

I'm not really sure what a bounty is or does. However, I did answer my own question — in case anyone else needed the answer for something similar — and I am not allowed to vote for my own answer. What is proper Stack Overflow etiquette in this situation?

Comment: Questions about "bounty" are well covered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to vote for your own answer, correct. Because *obviously* you think your answer is helpful, as you wrote it.

If you haven't found a solution to your problem, you can open a bounty and give some of you reputation to another user that correctly answers your question.

However, if you have already found a solution that no one has provided an answer for, you can answer your own question and accept your answer. This can only be done 2 days after the question is posted.

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your own question is completely legit. But as you mentioned, you aren't allowed to upvote it. Others should give their opinion on the quality of the answer.